# problems with Tascam DR-680 freezing up

Tags: audio-recording

I have started having problems with my dr-680 freezing up. I have to remove power to get it to turn off, and then all recording is lost. Anyone else have this problem, and know of a solution?

Answer (score 1):

check with different SD card. if the problem persists, probably the hardware is malfunctioning. I never ever had problems with dr-680 freezing up. I bet it's the sd media.